# JavaScript: if let / if-scoped let

Tags: javascript

I cannot seem to find anything similar to `if let` from other programming languages in JavaScript.

If I want to get the logo text of Stack Overflow I need to do

```
let text = document.querySelector('[class="-img _glyph"]')
if(text) {
    result = text.innerText
    //do some other work
}
```

So after declaring, I have to check for it to not be `undefined` first before using it. Now what would be much more logical is the following:

```
if let text = document.querySelector('[class="-img _glyph"]') {
    result = text.innerText
    //do some other work
}
```

which however doesn't work in JavaScript. Is there another syntax that I can use to avoid having to use the extra line just for the undefined-check?

I found this 10 year old thread https://esdiscuss.org/topic/if-scoped-let but since there were no further responses, I don't know if there is already anything that solves this.

Comment: `result = text?.innerText;` - `result` will be either `undefined` or the text, and no exception will be thrown.

Comment: It's called "conditional chaining" if you want to look it up.

Comment: Thank you for you guys' comments - in that instance, optional chaining makes sense however in other instances I would like to run extra code in case the result is not undefined. I have modified the question to make this more clear

Comment: Well there is no updated syntax to allow that. The `if` condition syntax does not allow for a declaration in the way that the `for` loop header does.

Comment: `const result = document.querySelector('[class="-img _glyph"]')?.innerText`

Comment: @Pointy First time I hear that term. In my head it's *optional* chaining.

Comment: @connexo I'm terrible about terminology but that's what MDN calls it.

Comment: @Pointy No: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @connexo ah I think it was Safari's auto-complete that was giving me that term, not MDN.  Like I said, "that question mark thing" is about my speed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, then the answer could be to use a `for` loop:

```js
for (let text = document.querySelector('[class="-img _glyph"]'); text; text = false) {
  result = text.innerText;
  console.log(result);
}
console.log("done");
```

Alternatively - and more in line with a maintainable code - you could do

```js
{
  let text = document.querySelector('[class="-img _glyph"]');
  if (text) {
    result = text.innerText;
    console.log(result);
  }
  console.log("text:", text);
}
console.log(text) // will throw an error!
```

Comment: If `'[class="-img _glyph"]'` is found, the code enters an endless loop since there is no way to end the loop. Add `break` after the inner `console.log` to escape the loop.

Comment: Yep - point taken! Add `text=false`  as a third part of the `for` loop and it will work again - or put in the `break` as suggested by @deaponn.

Comment: For anyone reading this answer in the future: While this technically works, please for the sake of anyone maintaining your code, just use an if statement instead.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, except for the overhead it adds to the whole line of code :/

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable within the if, but you can do an assignment and check that it's not undefined pretty easily:

```
let text, result;
if (text = document.querySelector('[class="-img _glyph"]')) {
  result = text.innerText
  //do some other work
} else {
  result = "not found";
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat close to what I intend to achieve however this declares the variable somewhat globally, is there any way around that? Like an `if (let text`? (mind the `let` in between for the scope)

Comment: No you can't do that.  This is as close as I can think of.